# Undo an event or bind it to second and next event() [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got code which is supposed to hide elements when I select them.

If I change my select every other element will be already hiden and I don't know how to trigger it back without an unpleasant visual effect .

**Can I undo this event or precise to an other event that it shall be trigger only the second time my select tag is change ?**

[image]

---

```
$('#departureCitys').change( function() {
    $('.products_dispo').each(function () {
        if($(this).find('.cityName').text() != $('#departureCitys').find(":selected").text()){
            $(this).toggle();
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use [jQuery's filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, render results based on callback of filter function.

Comment: This is a good Idea but the problem while remain mostly the same. Even if I use something like one(trigger the function) and then triger the function with the filter value; it will toggle twice the same value...
I'll need something to specify the second time you use the function do ...

Comment: i think you need to reset the values before you use second time and then apply your filters. you can use something like $(this).show()  in the beginning.

Comment: Ok It was as easy as this :)

Comment: But this is still not answering my first question. I'm curious :D